# Special characters appearing as question marks

Tags: python, input, encoding, character, output

Using the Python programming language, I'm having trouble outputting characters such as å, ä and ö. The following code gives me a question mark (?) as output, not an å:

```
#coding: iso-8859-1
input = "å"
print input
```

The following code lets you input random text. The for-loop goes through each character of the input, adds them to the string variable a and then outputs the resulting string. This code works correctly; you can input å, ä and ö and the output will still be correct. For example, "år" outputs "år" as expected.

```
#coding: iso-8859-1
input = raw_input("Test: ")
a = ""
for i in range(0, len(input)):
    a = a + input[i]
print a
```

What's interesting is that if I change `input = raw_input("Test: ")` to `input = "år"`, it will output a question mark (?) for the "å".

```
#coding: iso-8859-1
input = "år"
a = ""
for i in range(0, len(input)):
     a = a + input[i]
print a
```

For what it's worth, I'm using TextWrangler, and my document's character encoding is set to ISO Latin 1. What causes this? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have tried `print u"år"`?

Comment: Does this mean that user inputs are always encoded as Unicode?

Answer (score 3):

You're using Python 2, I assume running on a platform like Linux that encodes I/O in UTF-8.

Python 2's `""` literals represent byte-strings. So when you specify `"år"` in your ISO 8859-1-encoded source file, the variable `input` has the value `b'\xe5r'`. When you `print` this, the raw bytes are output to the console, but show up as a question-mark because they are not valid UTF-8.

To demonstrate, try it with `print repr(a)` instead of `print a`.

When you use `raw_input()`, the user's input is already UTF-8-encoded, and so are correctly output.

To fix this, either:

- Encode your string as UTF-8 before printing it:

  ```
  print a.encode('utf-8')
  ```
- Use Unicode strings (`u'text'`) instead of byte-strings. You will need to be careful with decoding the input, since on Python 2, `raw_input()` returns a byte-string rather than a text string. If you know the input is UTF-8, use `raw_input().decode('utf-8')`.
- Encode your source file in UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1. Then the byte-string literal will already be in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you very much! By adding the .decode('utf-8') part, the problem was solved. Thank you very much! :)