# Python print() outputs questionmarks

Tags: python, printing, pycharm

I am fairly new to python itself AND this forum.
I looked before if I found my problem here but haven't found a similar question before.

So I am currently working on a very very basic Tamagotchi and it has some sort of "easter egg- end credits".

It's a simple ascii (I think it's called that) copy pasta that repeats itself over and over, so it appears to be moving.
I use Pycharm, inside that if I hit Start it shows the copy pasta perfectly well.
But when I start the script outside the pycharm it only shows small Questionmark squares.

Specs:
Python 3
Pycharm
Windows 10

Hopefully someone can help me! 
Also sorry if I said something wrong I am new :(!

```
achievement = True
            while achievement == True:
                clear()
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣠⣶⣶⣤⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡞⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⢃⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠘⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣧⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢈⣽⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢿⣷⣦⣀⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠄⢉⣻⣿⡇⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢠⣿⣿⡉⣀⣿⣿⣿⣿⣋⣴⣿⠟⠋⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣠⣴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣏⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣀⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣮⡠⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⢰⣾⣿⣿⡿⠿⠛⠛⠛⠉⠄⠄⠄⠄⠙⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣆⡀⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠹⣿⣿⣦⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢉⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠂")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⢿⣿⣇⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣴⣾⣿⡿⠟⠉⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠂⢿⣿⣥⡄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣠⣶⣿⣿⠟⠋⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣀⣤⣾⣿⣿⣷⣿⣃⡀⢴⣿⣿⡿⣿⣍⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠄⠄⠄⠉⠙⠛⠛⠛⠛⠂⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                sleep(1.25)
                clear()
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⠄⣠⣶⣶⣷⣿⣶⡊⠄⠄⣀⣤⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣀⣴⣶⣾⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣿⣿⡏⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢸⣿⡍⠁⠄⠈⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠏⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠋⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣡⣶⣶⣄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣀⣀⣠⣴⣦⡤⣿⣿⣿⣿⡻⣿⣿⡯⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢻⣿⣿⡏⠉⠙⠛⢛⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢿⣿⡧⠄⠄⢠⣾⣿⣿⡿⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⣿⣿⣄⣼⣿⣿⣿⠏⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠸⡿⣻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣆⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⣻⠟⠈⠻⢿⣿⣿⣆⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠿⠍⠄⠄⠄⠄⠉⠻⣿⣷⡤⣀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⢻⣿⡿⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⡯⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠸⠃⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                sleep(1.25)
                clear()
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢠⣴⣧⣤⣴⡖⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣰⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣀⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣶⡄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠘⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣆⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣰⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡆⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⢤⣴⣦⣄⣀⣀⣴⣿⡟⢿⣿⡿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠉⠉⠙⠻⠿⣿⡿⠋⠄⠈⢀⣀⣠⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣇⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣠⣴⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡏⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣶⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⠉⠋⠉⠉⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠛⠛⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣇⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣠⣶⣿⣿⠿⢛⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣤⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣶⣷⣿⣿⡉⠄⠄⠄⠄⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠘⠛⠟⢿⣤⣤⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                sleep(1.25)
                clear()
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣤⣄⠄⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⡒⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⡀⣹⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣯⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣀⣀⣴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠋⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣀⣤⣶⣾⠿⠿⠿⠿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⡶⣶⡿⠛⠛⠉⠉⠄⠄⠄⠄⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠃⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠘⠃⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢠⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣤⣾⣷⣿⣿⣿⣿⡏⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣠⣴⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠂⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⢀⣤⣴⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠛⠻⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠸⣿⣿⣿⣿⠋⠉⠄⠄⠄⠄⣼⣿⣿⡿⠇⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠈⠻⣿⣿⣆⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣿⣿⣿⣷⡀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠻⣿⣿⣆⡀⠄⠄⠈⠻⣿⣿⣿⣦⡄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣀⣌⣿⣿⣿⣦⡄⠄⠄⠄⠙⠻⣿⣿⣦⣀⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠘⠻⣿⢿⢖⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                print("⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠉⠉⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄")
                sleep(1.25)
                clear()
```

and here a screenshot of what I see when I run it outside pycharm:
[image: and here a screenshot of what I see when I run it outside pycharm]

Comment: Edit your question to include the code. Don't provide links to your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special characters appearing as question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882935/special-characters-appearing-as-question-marks)

Comment: Those characters are not in the traditional ascii range. Likely your terminal doesn't support them. Try `import sys;print(sys.getdefaultencoding(), sys.stdout.encoding)` and post it for us. If its not unicode (utf-8, utf-16), that'll be it.

Comment: These are braille characters and it could be that you just haven't installed braille fonts.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - OP is using python 3 and there is no indication that an encoding like `#coding: iso-8859-1` has been set in the source. I don't think that reference applies.

Comment: @tdelaney so well I copied your code and pasted it, still nothing happened.
The only thing that appeared there was this utf-8 thing. Just confused now.
Also installing the braille font didn't change anything.